# How to use powershell detect whether NetOps Security Server stop or running?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have NetOps Security Server running on my server but I realize that sometime it will stop silenctly in background. How can I use powershell script to check whether it Running or Stop? Is that any part in get-process can know something like the status of the app?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `Get-Service` instead

Comment: Actually I also have write another code to check the service already. But some time I realize service is running but the one I show in picture is stop. So I thinking whether anyplace can know it stop.